# Jackrabbit Performance goes down on saving node

Tags: java, performance, database-performance, jackrabbit, jcr

I'm Using jackrabbit to store assets(contains text + image files).
Here is My workspace structure.

```
       root
        |
      node1
  //////|\\\\\\
      nodes(each node has 5-7 child for file type)
      //|\\   
    file type
////////|\\\\\\\
around 25-75 child file nodes(versionable) in each parent node

I have also some referenceable node (50-100) which are referenced by many nodes.
```

I have more than 55000 files. I'm Using File System Datastore to store file.

```
<DataStore class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.data.FileDataStore">
    <param name="path" value="${rep.home}/repository/datastore"/>
    <param name="minRecordLength" value="100"/>
</DataStore>
```

I imported all file in repository in structure i explain above.
Now when i'm saving session after adding node it takes too long time.
5-6 minute for storing 60-70 nodes.
Write operation takes long time. reading is taking normal time.

I'm using MSSQL database. And Jackrabbit implemented in java with spring framework.

So any possible solution for increase performance for adding new node.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have nodes with more than a few thousand child nodes in your structure? That might cause such slowness with Jackrabbit.

Comment: Did you try to save nodes one by one or by small bunches instead of saving them in the same time.

Comment: thanks @Ali I'm doing this only. I'm saving session after adding 5 nodes.